# How can I call a main function of a Java class?

Tags: java

E.g: I got a Java class with the main function implemented like this:

```
public class Job{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Job jobA = new Job();
        String jobName = System.getProperty("JobName");
        job.DoJobA("jobName");
    }

    public void DoJobA(String jobName){
        String configPath = System.getProperty("ConFig");
        File file = new File(configPath+ "/" + jobName);
        DoJobB(file);
    }
}
```

And I another class and want to call the main function of class Job but couldn't find a way to do that!
Is there any advise for me?

Comment: Why do you want to call only `main` method of another class? Can't you write any other simple method & call it?

Comment: @RAS you are right. It's a better pattern to put the code in another method, and call this new method from both main and the other class.

Comment: Since this class was written by another one and I dont want to change it!
And this class is used to be called by a shell script file, and it is easy to pass in system property when using shell script to run that main function! 
Just dont know how to handle it using Java!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to call it like you call any other static method

`Job.main(yourArgs);`

Comment: is that something like this?
Job.main(new String[]{"File1","Config1"};
and How can the program tell which argument is for the jobName and which argument is for the Config?

Comment: Yes. The main method accepts an array of strings as argument. You can pass any string array you like. It is not a set of key-value pairs as i think you expect. For example, it cannot tell you which parameter is which readily. That would be application's responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the main method use var args then you dont need to pass in any variable

```
public static void main(String... args) throws Exception{
    ...
}
```

then you can just call it as

```
Job.main();
```

if you need arguments then you can pass them if.